# Control a template used by 3 rd party used in DocuSign through different DocuSign account

Tags: docusignapi

A 3rd party website is offering our service to their members. When they sign up, members have to agree to contract which comprises of a section from 3rd party and one section of our organisation.  We want to streamline this process allowing us to control the template which is being used by 3rd party.

We want to control a part of envelope, one template document of our organisation through our account, although this envelope would contain a template from their account as well.

Currently our agreement template is maintained on 3rd party account and any changes which are needed, we have to request them and they fail at incorporating them properly.

The 3rd party web site will collect the member information, then use the REST API to create a draft envelope based on a Template and information the the member enters on the website. The application will then display the contract in the web page so that the user can review and sign it. The document workflow will ensure that signed copies are routed to appropriate parties within appropriate companies

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't fully understand your question. Is the sender using the API to create the envelope?

An envelope is controlled by the sender. If you want to provide a document that will be used by someone else within an envelope, then I suggest that you set up a web service that will used by the sender to retrieve the signer-specific document from you.

The sender will then include your document in the envelope sent to the signer. Since your web service will supply the document, you'll be in control of your document, your part of the overall envelope that will be sent to the signer.